# How to select a daterange of files and archive them?

Tags: batch-file, archive

We have 4 servers (Windows 2003 R2), each with a log-directory with thousands of log-files. I have written a log-viewer that collect log-files within a date range and show them in a grid. But this is rather slow as the number of log-files grow fast.

If I could schedule to move all files older than N days to an zip-archive I think the logviewer should be much faster. I'm not good at write bat-files. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What type of logs?

Comment: It is custom logs in textfiles for a server application written by our team. It as timestamp and a message, maybe an exception string etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`forfiles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx):

```
forfiles /m *.log /c <zip up here> /d -N
```

The `/d` switch tells `forfiles` to only consider files older than N days. Of course, you need to replace N with a nice number.